# Review form using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to build an online store for my project, and i wish i could add a review form in one of my pages, i am getting a problem with inserting the input value into the array ! here is my files

details.html

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div ng-controller="reviewController">
                    <h3 class="pdt-title">Review</h3><hr>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="reviews.length == 0">
                        No reviews yet, be the first to review this Product!
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="review in reviews" >
                    <blockquote class="row">
                        <h3 class="pdt-title col-sm-6">{{review.username}}</h3>
                        <h3 class="pdt-title col-sm-6">{{review.star}}</h3>
                        <h5 class="col-sm-12"><small><i>{{review.email}}</i></small></h5>
                        <p class="col-sm-12">{{review.message}}</p>
                    </blockquote>
                    </div>
                    <form class="form-inline form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">Name</span>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="username"></input>

                            <span class="input-group-addon">E-mail</span>
                            <input class="form-control" type="email" ng-model="email"></input>

                            <span class="input-group-addon">Star</span>
                            <select class="form-control" ng-model="star">
                                <option name="oneStar" value="1 star">1 Star</option>
                                <option name="twoStar" value="2 star">2 Star</option>
                                <option name="threeStar" value="3 star">3 Star</option>
                                <option name="fourStar" value="4 star">4 Star</option>
                                <option name="fiveStar" value="5 star">5 Star</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" ng-model="message"></textarea><br>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success" ng-submit="addReview()" value="Submit review"></input>


                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and here is my controller

app.js

```
app.controller('reviewController',function($scope){
$scope.reviews=[];
$scope.addReview=function(){
    $scope.reviews.push({
        name:$scope.username,
        email:$scope.email,
        star:$scope.star,
        message:$scope.message
    });
};
});
```

it would be great if someone explains the comments staying on the page even when the page is refreshed, usually the comments get lost when the page is refreshed.

Comment: Reason why your comments are getting lost, is because when you reload the page, controller is getting reinitialized and setting the $scope.reviews = []. So to avoid this, you should add logic of pushing the reviews in service. And in controller fetch the comments like this $scope.reviews= ReviewService.getReview().

Comment: thanks, but the problem here is i am not able to insert any comment into array itself ! i dont know where the problem occur, even when call the function addReview() by clicking the submit button no action is performed.

Comment: The problem is with your ng-submit button. Here is a fiddle working: http://jsfiddle.net/joaopgrassi/tbfp3e2p/

Comment: thank you jpgrassi, that worked ! will you update the fiddle in such a way that the comment stays on the page even when i refresh the page ?

Comment: You mean the "saved" comments? If yes, you have to actually persist the comments somewhere (eg. database). Every time you refresh the page your scope is destroyed that's why it's not there. $scope is not persistent,  inside your controller you should fetch the comments from the database. I've provided an answer for your initial question.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, you should load your comments from somewhere. A service should do the job.

But your problem was with your ng-submit button. Didn't inspect in deep but I changed to ng-click and it worked. Also, be sure to always place your "fields" inside an object and not directly on the $scope.

```
//Set the models inside an object
$scope.review = {};
```

And then

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="review.username" />
```

Here's an updated:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joaopgrassi/qLkdcxLc/)

As an extra tip, if you haven't check this awesome guide yet you should save some time and read through it:
[angular-styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)

It contains a compilation of angular best practices written by John Papa.